# IE new session C# wininet?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer-8, wininet

I've seen several articles on how wininet can force a web browser control to start a new session (the equivalence of opening IE, going to File and then clicking New Session).

Is this correct or am I misunderstanding? If it is possible, could someone point me in the direction of the reference material(s) that could get me started with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try InternetSetOption(0, INTERNET_OPTION_END_BROWSER_SESSION,
                               0, 0)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195192)

Comment: Given the example with the link you provided, what do I do with h? (I put the vb code through http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/, apologies for the ineptitude and delay.)